# PRIORVALUE function cannot reference the Account.BillingCountry field with error on ischanged(Account.BillingCountry)

Tags: formula, validation

Trying to create formula like :

```
AND( 
RecordType.DeveloperName = 'recType' ,
ISCHANGED(AccountId),
Product_Cnt__c<>0,
OR(
AND(
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Account.BillingCountry),Account.BillingCountry), 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Account.BillingCountry,Account.BillingCountry))
),
AND(
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Account.BillingCountry),Account.BillingCountry), 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Account.BillingCountry,Account.BillingCountry)))
)
)
```

However unable to save and getting The PRIORVALUE function cannot reference the Account.BillingCountry field. Unable to use ischanged(Account.BillingCountry)

Comment: You cannot use ISCHANGED and PRIORVALUE with relation fields. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to check if opportunity related account billing country is not same as previously present.

Comment: do you want to allow account change if country is the same, and fire validation if country of the new account is different than the previous one?